# What is this notation: "//@" in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, source-maps

The minified jQuery library file contains this comment at the top:

```
/*! jQuery v2.0.2 | (c) 2005, 2013 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license
//@ sourceMappingURL=jquery-2.0.2.min.map
*/
```

Chrome is making requests for that file which isn't being found.

What is the meaning of the line starting with `//@`? Is it only used for source maps? Googling three non-alpha-numeric characters isn't yielding many results.

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/ but see also: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/06/sourceMappingURL-and-sourceURL-syntax-changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's for source maps.

"This enables developer tools to map calls back to their location in original source files."

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/
http://globaldev.co.uk/2013/01/happy-debugging-with-javascript-source-maps/

Comment: So it is *only* for source maps? Are there plans to extend that syntax for other uses later?

Comment: I am only aware of its use in context with source maps. And actually, according to http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/ the syntax has actually changed in the latest browser versions to "//#", due to a conflict with IE's conditional statment syntax "@cc_on".